# Working with directories and file paths in Microsoft R Server

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

I am writing a stored procedure on my SQL Server database where I have a file path as the SPROC parameter.

I then do some `foreach` work in an Rscript that writes results along the way to a `.csv`.

Regardless, I can't even get Microsoft R to change the working directory or recognize filepaths.

Here's an example of a SPROC:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rscript_geocodeUSACities_TEST]
    @usrOutputFilePath varchar(150)
    ,@usrOutputFileName varchar(150)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rScript nvarchar(max) = N'

usrOutputFile <- "' + @usrOutputFilePath + @usrOutputFileName + '"
setwd("' + @usrOutputFilePath + '")
print(getwd())
print(usrOutputFile)
print(file.exists(usrOutputFile))



'

EXECUTE  sp_execute_external_script
                @language = N'R'
              , @script = @rScript
              ;

END
```

and then execute the SPROC:

```
exec [dbo].[Rscript_geocodeUSACities_TEST]
    @usrOutputFilePath = 'C:/Users/boswelpa/Desktop/Projects/MDM/R/Geographies/USA - Cities/Output/'
    ,@usrOutputFileName = 'USA_Cities_Clean.csv'
```

Comment: What output do you get after you run this procedure? It's very possible that the users that run R code inside the database (local users in SQLRUserGroup with very limited permissions) do not have read permissions on the folder where you've put the .csv file. I'd specifically give SQLRUserGroup permissions to read files in that folder.

Comment: As @BobAlbright asks, what is the output? Also, do you see any errors in the logfiles at: `C:\path_to_instance\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog`? I just ran your code (with modified path and filename) on my SQL Server 2016 machine, and it worked fine. Also, as @BobAlbright says, check for permissions.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it's a permissions issue.  Sorry I didn't catch this earlier!